# How to convert these lines of c code to c++

Tags: c++, c, porting

I'm trying to import some c code into my c++ program.  There are three lines that don't import directly:

The first:

```
free(t);
```

The second:

```
new_node = (Tree *) malloc (sizeof (Tree));
```

The third:

```
Tree * delete(int value, Tree * t)
```

How can these be changed to work in C++?

Comment: Error message are really awesome.  Otherwise we are all just guessing.  

One note is delete is a keyword in c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two lines should be valid C++, assuming you've included stdlib.h, and have defined Tree as a class/struct/type somewhere.

The third line will need to be changed, since 'delete' is a keyword in C++ and can't be used as a function name.  Try doing a global replace in the C code and changing all instances of 'delete' with 'delete_from_tree' or something like that.

Answer (score 5):

You can use free and malloc in C++.  Whether you should is a different story, but if you're porting a C library the answer to that is yes (at least for now).

`delete` is a keyword in C++, you will need to rename that function.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want convert it to C++ style new/delete (see other answers about continuing to use malloc/free):

```
// 1. free(t);
delete t;

// 2. new_node = (Tree *) malloc (sizeof (Tree));
new_node = new Tree;

// 3. Tree * delete(int value, Tree * t)
Tree * delete_tree(int value, Tree* t)
```

Note: for #3, you will need to change all users of `delete(value, t)` to `delete_tree(value, t)`.